# sharing interfaces with web services in .net

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, interface

I am using a web service.  I define an interface in the web service.

Can I use this interface definition in my project that invokes the web service?  I know I can use classes defined in the web service.

Do I have to do anything special with the interface like add an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you generate the service client add a reference to the assembly containing the interfaces and enable the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" in the client generation interface. It should use the already existing types instead of generating new ones.